# User Object gets excecuted before the compressed picture gets saved, how can i change that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, blob

I have a problem. I want to compress am image and store it into the local host. The problem is that the `image.onload` is executed after the object is created

```
            var oneUser = {
              id: user.user.id_profile,
              username: user.user.username,
              image: user_image,
            };
            users.push(oneUser);
```

I tried it with the keyword `await` but unfortunately it doesn't work. How could I save the compress blob url into the user object that the localstorage  has the blob url.

```
const getChat = () => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:4000/chat/rooms/${chatid}`, {})
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          
          var users = [];
          res.data.users.map((user) => {

            // BASE64 zu Blob URL
            var user_image = "";
            image =  user.user.image.split(",");
            image = image[1]
            const contentType = 'image/png';
            const b64Data = image;
            const blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
            const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log(blobUrl)
            // Blob komporemieren
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = blobUrl;
            image.onload = function() {
               var  resized =  resizeMe(image); // resized image url
               // BASE64 zu Blob Url
              resized = resized.split(",");
              resized = resized[1]
              const contentType = 'image/png';
              const b64Data = resized;
              const blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
              user_image = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              console.log(user_image)
            }
  
            
            console.log(user_image)
            var oneUser = {
              id: user.user.id_profile,
              username: user.user.username,
              image: user_image,
            };
            users.push(oneUser);
          });
          //console.log(users)
          localStorage.removeItem(`userList_${chatid}`);
          localStorage.setItem(`userList_${chatid}`,JSON.stringify(users));
         
          console.log("HALLO")
         
     

          setInitalMessages(res.data);
          scrollToBottom();
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };


// === RESIZE ====

const resizeMe = (img) =>  {
  
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  var max_width = 50
  var max_height = 50
  var width = img.width;
  var height = img.height;
  console.log(width)
  console.log(height)
  // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
  if (width > height) {
    if (width > max_width) {
      //height *= max_width / width;
      height = Math.round(height *= max_width / width);
      width = max_width;
      
    }
  } else {
    if (height > max_height) {
      //width *= max_height / height;
      width = Math.round(width *= max_height / height);
      height = max_height;
      
    }
  }
  
  // resize the canvas and draw the image data into it
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  
  return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.7); // get the data from canvas as 70% JPG (can be also PNG, etc.)
  
  // you can get BLOB too by using canvas.toBlob(blob => {});

}



  const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];
  
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
  
      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }
  
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
  
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of the code works fine, then I would say the only thing you need to change is to place the "oneUser" variable creation inside the "image.onload" callback, because that's where the asynchronous action is taking place.

```
// ...

image.onload = function() {
    var  resized =  resizeMe(image); // resized image url
    // BASE64 zu Blob Url
    resized = resized.split(",");
    resized = resized[1]
    const contentType = 'image/png';
    const b64Data = resized;
    const blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
    user_image = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(user_image)

    // INITIALIZE THE USER HERE
    var oneUser = {
       id: user.user.id_profile,
       username: user.user.username,
       image: user_image,
    };
    users.push(oneUser);
    
    // SAVE THE USERS
    localStorage.removeItem(`userList_${chatid}`);
    localStorage.setItem(`userList_${chatid}`,JSON.stringify(users));
}
  
// ...
```

Since events are not Promise-based, you cannot await such an action with the async-await syntax (unless you create a Promise wrapper for it, but I think it would be unnecessary).

Comment: thank you for your comment. I tried the same. The problem is that code snippet `localStorage.setItem('userList_${chatid}',JSON.stringify(users));`  if I paste the `user` in the `image.onload` callback the `localStorage` will save an empty object. :/

Comment: Ok, I didn't see it was used there, in this situation, you could just put that command inside the callback as well! If the other command also require the users to be saved first, then you can put them all in there. This is the reason async-await was introduced, to avoid the "callback hell". I'm updating my answer accordingly :)